# How to compare 2 lists and remove duplicates from 1 efficiently?

Tags: python

I need to compare 2 lists and remove elements that appear in the first array from the second one efficiently. My solutions below:

**Homebrew algorithm**:

```
#function accepts 2 arrays. Compares elements from 1st array to 2nd to see if they exist in 2nd, 
#and removes them from 2nd array. 
def compareRemove(self, array1 = [], array2 = []):

    #starting iteration values
    i = 0
    j = 0

    array1_length = len(array1)
    array2_length = len(array2)

    while i < array1_length:
        while j < array2_length:

            #compare element from first array to second array, remove element if same, 
            #and update second array length
            if array1[i] == array2[j]:

                del array2[j]
                array2_length = len(array2)

            #otherwise move j forward
            else:
                j = j + 1

        #when 2nd while loop is done move i forward and reset j to 0
        i = i + 1
        j = 0

    return array2
```

**suggested from research on SO:**

`updated_file_strings = [x for x in array2 if not x in array1]`

Both are similarly fast, however as my array lenghts increase both will slow down. Are there any methods I can utilise that will perform well even if array lengths increase? Order doesnt matter.

**EXAMPLE:**

`array1 = [1, 2, 3]`
`array2 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5]`

`result_array = [5, 5, 5]`

duplicates within the second array should **NOT** be removed.

Comment: Please create a minimal, verifiable example and your expected output so we can better help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to `set`, remove elements, then convert back to `list`.

```py
s1 = set(array1)
s2 = set(array2)
array2 = list(s2.difference(s1))
```

Edit: To keep track of duplicates, you can use `collections.Counter` and reconstruct the list.

```py
from collections import Counter

s1 = set(array1)
array2 = [x for x in array2 if x not in s1]
# d2 = Counter(array2)
# array2 = [z for k, v in d2.items() if k not in s1 for z in [k] * v]
```

EDIT2: I thought using `Counter` would be faster, but the secondary list construction in the comprehension seems to nullify any gains.  You are better off just making the first `set`, then using that for existence checks.

Tests: `Counter` and double comprehension

```
%%timeit
array1 = [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(200000)]
array2 = [random.randint(0, 20000) for _ in range(200000)]
s1 = set(array1)
d2 = Counter(array2)
[z for k, v in d2.items() if k not in s1 for z in [k]*v]

# returns:
525 ms ± 19.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Test: single comprehension with existence check

```
%%timeit
array1 = [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(200000)]
array2 = [random.randint(0, 20000) for _ in range(200000)]
s1 = set(array1)
#d2 = Counter(array2)
[x for x in array1 if x not in s1]

# returns:
510 ms ± 17.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I can't because set will remove any duplicates from array2.  I need them to count frequencies. Which is why I compare to remove only same elements that exist in both arrays. The dupes that exist within array2 should not be removed.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thank you James, that helps a lot. Not sure why my question was closed its nowhere near a duplicate suggested by Daniel. Probably didn't even read the question...